# Workbox fallback response with networkFirst strategy

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I am using Workbox in my service worker and I use [this strategy](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#provide_a_fallback_response_to_a_route) to provide a fallback response to a route that should show when offline and page is not in cache:

```
const FALLBACK_URL = '/offline/';

const urlHandler = workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'page-cache'
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /\/.+\//,
    ({event}) => {
        return urlHandler.handle({event})
            .catch(() => caches.match(FALLBACK_URL));
    });
```

This works well (I have alreaedy cached FALLBACK_URL) when I use staleWhileRevalidate strategy and when I use networkOnly strategy. However, I would really like to use networkFirst strategy but when I try that I get the following error when visiting pages that are not in the cache:

[image]

and the console says

'The FetchEvent for "https://staging.bassbuddha.com/pedals/" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().'

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I am using version 3.4.1
https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.4.1/workbox-sw.js

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that this is intentional as per [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1551#issuecomment-400426566) on the Workbox GitHub repo. Here is the quote on networkFirst (as opposed to other strategies) by jeffposnick:

> networkFirst does not end up throwing in that scenario because the
>   underlying network exception triggers a cache.match() lookup, and
>   cache.match() doesn't throw/reject when there's a cache miss. Instead,
>   it resolves with undefined.

So the solution to fallback with networkFirst with fallback in Workbook is to catch *undefined* in the response and match it to the fallback url like so:

```
const FALLBACK_URL = '/offline/';

const urlHandler = workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
    cacheName: 'page-cache'
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /\/.+\//,
    ({event}) => {
        return urlHandler.handle({event})
            .then((response) => {
                return response || caches.match(FALLBACK_URL);
            })
            .catch(() => caches.match(FALLBACK_URL));
    });
```

Comment: At which point does workbox cache the offline page? That's what I don't understand. Normally, you would cache the offline page at the `install` event